# Truffle Test Non responsive After Execution

Tags: truffle

So I am trying to run test for my truffle project. The following is my structure.

I did truffle init and it created all the structures/folders.

All I created was the Zazzle.test.js

When I went to command line and run `truffle test`, it just lags and is non responsive. in the first picture...

Any idea why?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What are the specs of your work environment?

Comment: Im using Mac Big Sur 11.5.2, using truffle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being so new to Truffle and solidity dev, I found out that I had the uncomment the "developement" section under `truffle-config.js`

Note that the correct port number can be found in the top right of Ganache 'gear icon'.

[image]